# How to Automate export dataset to Power BI file using python script

Tags: python, powerbi

I have a power BI report that uses SQL server and the data set in xlsx format. I need to export this to dataset  when ever I open powerbi file so that it automatically detects the dataset file which is present with the same name and display it using python script.

So is there any way possible to automate this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. In Power BI Desktop, select **File > Options and settings > Options > Python scripting**. The Python script options page appears, and just choose the python environment you are using.

To run your Python Script in Power BI Desktop:

In the **Home ribbon, select Get data > Other.**

**Select Other > Python script** as shown in the following image:

**Select Connect**. Your local latest installed Python version is selected as your Python engine. Copy your script into the Python script dialog box that appears.

Here is the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts).

And for reading Excel data. I would use `openpyxl`. Here is a small demo:

```
def xlsx_reader(): 
    data = []
    file_exist = os.path.exists('demo.xlsx')
    if file_exist:
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('demo.xlsx')
        wb1 = wb['demo']
        
        data.append(wb1['A1'].value)
    return data
```

Here is the [document](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for openpyxl.